# How to get first / last record

Tags: mysql

My question is very simple but I can't think how to Google it. :D I need to get a last row with the needed email address. My query gives me the first record.

What should I add here to get a last record with the needed email?

```
"SELECT userid, activation FROM users WHERE email = '$var1' LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: First, last, in what order? Use `ORDER BY`. Without, you basically ask for one row only (`LIMIT 1`) without specifying which.

Comment: Do you have an order column? If so, do `ORDER BY created_at DESC` with that column.

Comment: What you did you google for that didn't lead you to `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ORDER BY <field> DESC` to your query

```
SELECT userid, activation FROM users WHERE email = '$var1' ORDER BY email DESC LIMIT 1
```